# Assign the output of a pipe in angular2 to a variable

Tags: angular, pipes-filters

So I have a pipe like this:

```
 <ul *ngFor="#eachNumber of (NumberArray | MyPipe: '1')"></ul>
```

How can I assign the returned result of the pipe to a variable that can be used elsewhere in my code?

I've looked for a while and read about something called assign-local but couldnt find much information on it. Is there a obvious way to do this that I am just missing?

Comment: What's the purpose? Why would you need that?

Comment: I was more just curious to see if it could be done.

Comment: You can apply the pipe in your code, why applying it in markup to use the result in code?

Comment: I'm interested to know if there was ever a solution found. Gunter, the reason you might want that is so you aren't iterating over the list multiple times. It's wasted computation.

Comment: Instantiate the pipe in a component and call `transform()` on each array item.

Comment: To go along with @DanWilson's answer, the code will look like: `formattedNumber = myPipe.transform(eachNumber)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just in case anyone stumbled upon this question. This is possible with Angular 4 now, with the updated [`as` syntax](http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2017/03/24/what-is-new-angular-4/#as) :)

Comment: Yep. Just came across this :)

Comment: Can you add more explanations/examples on how to do that ?

Comment: I haven't used Angular for a long time. But I was able to find an example on Angular doc, so this syntax should still be supported with newest version of Angular.    

    <li *ngFor="let user of userObservable | async as users; index as i; first as isFirst">
        {{i}}/{{users.length}}. {{user}} <span *ngIf="isFirst">default</span>
    </li>
 
check https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf